# I want to uninstall l10n_client which may be duplicated

Tags: i18n-l10n, installation

I use composer.
The L10n_client module could not be updated or occasionally not found.
I feel that the names of L10n_client or l10n_client_ui are different.
It is a similar atmosphere as below.
https://www.drupal.org/node/2658756
I do not know if it is the same cause.
Since Composer update can not be done, I have memories that I executed composer require as override.

I got a message to install the l10n_client module under some circumstances, so I ran the installation on admin/modules, but an error was returned.
Localization Client Interface The module is unchecked.
Localization Client Contributor module is not installed.
Error message is ‘Unable to install Localization Client Interface, l10n_client_ui.settings already exists in active configuration.’

How can I solve it?

Environment:Drupal 8.4.2

Answer (score 2):

I ran "drush config-delete l10n_client_ui.settings".
I was able to install the module.